# Какие есть варианты решения проблемы загрзки изображений через этот скрипт, если он блокируется на уровне CORS?

Tags: javascript, cors, расширения

Написал небольшой скрипт, который скачивается изображение при нажатии на кнопку, но гадский cors блокирует такого рода попытки)) Что можно придумать?

```
(async function magicsas () {
    const url = document.getElementById('originalimage').getAttribute('href');
    const resp = await fetch(url);
    const blob = await resp.blob();
    const name = url.split("/").pop().replace("jpeg", "jpg");

    downloadBlob(blob, name, url);

    function downloadBlob(blob, name, url) {
        const anchor = document.createElement("a");
        anchor.setAttribute("download", name || "");
        const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        anchor.href = blobUrl + (url ? ("#" + url) : "");
        anchor.click();
        setTimeout(() => URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl), 3000);
    }
})();


document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 189) {
        //document.getElementById("highres").click();
        //console.log('Key -_');
        
        //var href = document.getElementById('originalimage').getAttribute('href');
        //console.log(href);
        
        magicsas();
    }
});
```

UPD/ 21.04.2023 - РЕШЕНИЕ ПРОБЛЕМЫ В ВИДЕ УСТАНОВКИ [РАСШИРЕНИЯ ДЛЯ БРАУЗЕРА](https://webextension.org/listing/access-control.html), КОТОРОЕ РЕГУЛИРУЕТ РАБОТУ CORS

Answer (score 3):

Ничего. Cors для того и нужен, чтобы его нельзя было обойти.

Comment: один друже предлагал 2 варианта.

1. "Используй юзерскрипт менеджер violentmonkey/tampermonkey c GM.xmlHttpRequest/GM_xmlHttpRequest." 2. бекграунд в расширении. А Вы говорите, что ничего

Comment: Что ж вы советом друже тогда не воспользовались? Дайте угадаю, он не работает. Потому что корс для того и предназначен чтоб блокировать запросы, и на фронтенде это нельзя изменить

Comment: @user453575457 не, я решил спросить на другом ресурсе) стало быть более популярней, чем хабр. а так я не пробовал ещё его варианты. буду, раз это единственное, что можно попробовать

Comment: violentmonkey/tampermonkey - это выполнение скрипта на том сайте, для которого корс разрешен. То есть рандомно у пользователя в любой вкладке это работать не будет , а 2 - это вообще общая ничего не значащая фраза

Comment: @user453575457, ну из расширения по идее можно. Но не в контексте страницы.

Comment: @Qwertiy я уже нашёл решение) Расширение для браузера

Answer (score 0):

Ребят, если кому будет полезно. [Расширение для браузера](https://webextension.org/listing/access-control.html), которое решает пролбему с CORS. Так что проблема решена, всем спасибо!